# How to define the "docker container run" args in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

My docker container run command line included a lot of args, for example:

```
docker container run --privileged --rm -u ${USER} -v $HOME:$HOME -e CURRENT_LOGLVL=$CURRENT_LOGLVL -it mydockerimg /bin/bash
```

reference for these [args](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/)

```
--privileged      Give extended privileges to this container
I need to run in privilege mode to give extended privileges to this container

-v                 Bind mount a volume
I need to access a NFS mount point inside the docker container

-u                 Username or UID
I need to use special user

--rm            Automatically remove the container when it exits

-i      Keep STDIN open even if not attached

-e              environment variable
```

I read some docs like
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

Environment variable and volume related information can be found.
But how to handle other args like `--privileged` and so on?

Is there some way to pass these args directly to docker?
OR
Is there anyway that I run the docker command line manually
but K8S have some way to transfer the docker container instance into a POD?

Thanks for any tips or links

Comment: The [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#pod-v1-core) definition in the Kubernetes API docs lists out all of the possible options.  Note that you will never be able to mount your local home directory into a pod, or specify a dynamic user ID, and even more so than Docker you really want a container that does something besides launch a shell.

Answer (score 1):

For privileged container and `-u` need use [secure context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/).
Also in kubernetes, you can use `--rm` flag.

Comment: Thank you.
I found following for user.


apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsGroup: 3000
    fsGroup: 2000

What about --privileged  ? I need to use loop device from host.